# Producing wrong output... Jquery / JS .getJSON .each .children .append .text this

Tags: jquery

I do not understand why this is running through the function 3 times (which i stopped with the runonce variable) but now its running 
if(runonce === 'true') when its not suppose too. 
Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.a1').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var tmp_name = $(this).text();
        var session_id = $('#hdnSession').val();
        var options = $(".t1");
        var runonce = 'true';
        if((session_id === "" )||(session_id === null)){
            alert("Please Log In");
        }else{            
            var holder = $.getJSON("./acc_db.php", function(data){      
                options.append("<tr>");                
                $.each(data, function() {
                    if(this.id === url) {
                        if(this.all_fields_submitted === 'true'){
                            options.children(":last").append($("<td />").text(this.S_Name));
                            options.children(":last").append($("<td />").text("is completed"));
                            runonce = 'false';
                        }else{
                            options.children(":last").append($("<td />").text(this.S_Name));
                            options.children(":last").append($("<td />").text("Needs to completed registration for"));
                            options.children(":last").append($("<td />").text(this.camp_Name));                            
                            options.children(":last").append($("<td />").text(this.firstChoice));                          
                            options.children(":last").append($("<td />").text(this.camp_Start_Date));
                            runonce = 'false';
                        }                        
                    }else{
                        if(runonce === 'true'){
                            options.children(":last").append($("<td />").text(tmp_name));
                            options.children(":last").append($("<td />").text("needs to register"));
                            runonce = 'false';
                        }

                    }
                });
            });
            options.append("</tr>");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You're using a `$.each` loop, so it will iterate over as many items are returned. What exactly is the problem you're having? I'm not sure what effect you're expecting `runonce` to have as it's defined in several places, but never actually used.

Comment: what do you mean by `when it is not suppose to`... do you mean in the second/third click... whether the `runonce === 'true'` is suppose to run only in the first click

Comment: Any reason why you're using `'true'` and `'false'` strings instead of `true` and `false` booleans?